# Is it idiomatic to call FEATURE_ACTION_BAR from code

Tags: android

My question is related to activating the ActionBar in an Android app. Is it more idiomatic to do `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR)` or is it more idiomatic to force that through the theme you are using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking what is the "best practice" as recommended by Google, take a look at the sample applications on the developer's page. You'll notice you don't see `requestFeature()` used. An Action Bar is default for all Holo themes, so in most cases you don't need to address this problem at all.

Even if you're using the new CompatLibrary, you should use it with a theme. The new [Action Bar Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Adding) doesn't even mention `requestFeature()`.

**Edit:**

Ah, the demos did have a use of this. However, even then they say it is "normally set by your Activity's theme" and tell you how to do that instead.

```
 // The Action Bar is a window feature. The feature must be requested
 // before setting a content view. Normally this is set automatically
 // by your Activity's theme in your manifest. The provided system
 // theme Theme.WithActionBar enables this for you. Use it as you would
 // use Theme.NoTitleBar. You can add an Action Bar to your own themes
 // by adding the element <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
 // to your style definition.
 getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
```